# No module named 'adspy_shared_utilities'

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, knn

I am trying to make a simple fruit classifier using sklearn in Python (for learning purposes). while plotting the decision boundaries of the k-NN classifier it shows the error "***No module named 'adspy_shared_utilities'*** ".

This is the screenshot of the code with the error-

[image: No module named 'adspy_shared_utilities']

Here is the code-

```
from adspy_shared_utilities import plot_fruit_knn

plot_fruit_knn(X_train, y_train, 5, 'uniform')   # we choose 5 nearest neighbors
```

Error -

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
1 from adspy_shared_utilities import plot_fruit_knn
3 plot_fruit_knn(X_train, y_train, 5, 'uniform')   # we choose 5 nearest neighbors

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adspy_shared_utilities'
```

How do I resolve this please?

I was expecting decision boundaries of the k-NN classifier with the code

```
from adspy_shared_utilities import plot_fruit_knn

plot_fruit_knn(X_train, y_train, 5, 'uniform')   # we choose 5 nearest neighbors
```

Comment: please add some context, this module you are missing is not a standard python module, so we have no idea why your code requires it.